# How can I get current buffer length of MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

How can I get current buffered length of MpMoviePlayer in **seconds**?
This [link](http://www.ciiycode.com/7mBNHzQWeXXe/mpmovieplayer-streaming-video-buffer-size) described how to get it in bytes, but I need to convert it to seconds.

Is there any way that I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `playableDuration` property of the `MPMoviePlayerController`.

According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/playableDuration),

> The amount of currently playable content. (read-only)
>
> **Declaration**
>
> ```
>    @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval playableDuration
> ```
>
> **Discussion** 
> For progressively downloaded network
> content, this property reflects the amount of content that can be
> played now.